# How do skimage.morphology.remove_small_holes and skimage.morphology.remove_small_objects differ?

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

Both of these methods are included in the Scikit-Image library for Python. I'm trying to extract certain objects from images and ran into these two methods in a senior dev's code, written for the same purpose.

I have read the documentation for both [`skimage.morphology.remove_small_holes`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.morphology.html#skimage.morphology.remove_small_holes) and [`skimage.morphology.remove_small_objects`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.morphology.html#skimage.morphology.remove_small_objects). But I can't understand what difference these two methods pose when they are run on a ndarray containing an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One removes holes (value 0) within objects (any other single value), the other removes objects. Note that it acts on either *binary images* (ndarray of dtype bool) or *segmentation masks* (ndarray of dtype int, where each value represents one object). Hopefully this example clarifies their use:

```py
import numpy as np
from skimage import morphology

objects = np.array([
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
        ])
```

You can see that this array has two objects, object "1" has 8 pixels, and a hole in it of size 1 pixel, while object "2" has only 1 pixel total. Now I do:

```py
print(morphology.remove_small_objects(objects, 2))
```

This removes objects of size strictly less than 2 pixels, so "2" disappears:

```
[[1 1 1 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Removing holes is a little more complicated, because that function *only* works with boolean arrays, but the same principle applies. We are going to:

- convert the object image to binary/boolean
- remove the holes
- use `segmentation.watershed` to get objects back — preserving their original IDs.

```py
from skimage import segmentation

binary_objects = objects.astype(bool)
binary_filled = morphology.remove_small_holes(binary_objects, 2)
objects_filled = segmentation.watershed(
        binary_filled, objects, mask=binary_filled
        )
print(objects_filled)
```

This removes from any object *holes* of size strictly less than 2, so the hole in the object "1" is removed:

```
[[1 1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 2]]
```